# How set Cache-Control headers for index.htm files using mod_headers?

Tags: apache-2.2, http-headers

I need to set cache control headers for index.htm files
Unfortunately the following configuration does not work.
The reason when the user access “/” in a browser the server response with index.htm even it does not appear in the request.

```
<filesMatch "(index.htm)$">
  <ifModule mod_headers.c>
      Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
      Header set Pragma "no-cache"
      Header set Expires 0
  </ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

How can I set cache control cookies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LocationMatch` instead of `FilesMatch`:

```
<LocationMatch "(\/|index\.(htm|html))$">
    <ifModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Expires 0
    </ifModule>
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not help.
Please remind that we do not have request “/index.htm” but only “/”

Comment: Now the location should match both `*/` and `*index.htm(l)`.